# Android Google Play Store automation to submit .apk

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to automate the app submission process in my project to Google Play Store. When I researched on this I find pretty amazing tools and libraries I have tried following libraries

https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane

https://github.com/bluesliverx/gradle-android-publisher

But these requires at least first manual upload of .apk file on Google Play Store. Is there any way where I can submit the app and its information without submitting test/beta apk to Google Play Store?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I have different flavors in my project and according to user need I will build the apk. So I don't want to publish apk manually each time.

Answer (score 1):

Fastlane (or other libs that uses Google Publishing API) requires you already have an App in Google Play. This is from Google's API website（https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/））:

> Publishing API The Google Play Developer Publishing API allows you to
>   automate frequent tasks having to do with app production and
>   distribution. This provides functions similar to those available to a
>   developer through the Developer Console, such as:
>
> **Uploading new versions of an app**
>
> Releasing apps, by assigning APKs to various Tracks (alpha, beta, staged rollout, or production)
>
> Creating and modifying Google Play Store listings, including localized
>   text and graphics and multi-device screenshots

So you can only "uploading new versions of an app"

Comment: This is correct. I'm currently working on a project that involves pushing packages automatically to the play store. It's not that hard, you just need to understand how the API works.